# Taking Exponential of a Sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

```
A=sc.array([[0,2,1],[2,0,3],[1,3,0]])    
sA = sp.csc_matrix(A)
Q2=np.exp(A)
print Q2
Q1=sp.linalg.expm(sA)
print (Q1)
```

I am working with large dataset adjacency matrix where I need to do exponential of the matrix(I am using the csc sparse matrix representation).I was testing for bugs using toy dataset like above and found the scipy.sparse.linalg.expm is giving different answer than numpy.exp for the same numpy array.Shouldnt it sparse.linalg give a close answer to the numpy one?
Both the outputs are attached.The answers are not even close.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.exp` is element by element exponential.  `expm` is a matrix exponential, a very different calculation.

```
In [539]: A = np.array([[0,2,1],[2,0,3],[1,3,0]])
In [541]: np.exp(A)
Out[541]: 
array([[  1.        ,   7.3890561 ,   2.71828183],
       [  7.3890561 ,   1.        ,  20.08553692],
       [  2.71828183,  20.08553692,   1.        ]])
In [542]: np.exp?
In [543]: np.exp(2)
Out[543]: 7.3890560989306504
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Computing_the_matrix_exponential'

```
In [545]: from scipy.sparse import linalg
In [547]: linalg.expm(A)
Out[547]: 
array([[ 13.45868182,  18.62459092,  16.65146966],
       [ 18.62459092,  26.50610262,  23.85956737],
       [ 16.65146966,  23.85956737,  21.61331982]])
```

I don't know if there's a function to do the sparse exponential, but the pieces can be evaluated with:

```
In [565]: sA = sparse.csc_matrix(A)
In [566]: np.exp(sA.data)
Out[566]: 
array([  7.3890561 ,   2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692,
         2.71828183,  20.08553692])
In [567]: np.exp(0)
Out[567]: 1.0
```

Since the `exp(0)` is 1, the result, even with a sparse matrix, is dense.  So it would be just as easy (and probably faster) to convert the sparse matrix to dense and do the dense calculation.

---

As @Desire commented, there is a `np.expm1` function.  And the sparse matrix has

```
In [574]: sA.expm1().A
Out[574]: 
array([[  0.        ,   6.3890561 ,   1.71828183],
       [  6.3890561 ,   0.        ,  19.08553692],
       [  1.71828183,  19.08553692,   0.        ]])
In [575]: sA.expm1().A+1
Out[575]: 
array([[  1.        ,   7.3890561 ,   2.71828183],
       [  7.3890561 ,   1.        ,  20.08553692],
       [  2.71828183,  20.08553692,   1.        ]])
```

This method applies `np.expm1` to its `data`, and returns a copy with the same sparsity.  `np.expm1(sA)` also works.

`sA.expm1()+1` does not work.  You have to make the matrix dense first.

Comment: How to do element wise exponential of a sparse matrix then?

Comment: The exponential will be dense, since `exp(0)` is 1.  So a sparse calculation , while possible, probably has few advantages.  See my edits.

Comment: Can np.exp handle large matrices?Also I need to do multiplication after obtaining the multiplication so wont it be inefficient to first convert the sparse to dense then again to sparse for multiplication?

Comment: Why do you need to go back to sparse for the multiplication?  The `exp`will not be sparse (unless the original has lots of `-inf` values.

Comment: Because multiplication of large matrices is more efficient in sparse

Comment: It is more efficient only if the matrix has a large % of zeros; in other words a sparsity of 10% or less.  Size isn't the issue; it's the number of non zero values.

Comment: One can apply `np.expm1` to a sparse matrix, which computes `exp(x)-1` elementwise. Since 0 is mapped to 0, sparsity is preserved. (That said, I don't know what one would need this sort of calculation for, in the context of adjacency matrix.) @ChaitaliSarkar